# Submit button (with Javascript) does not work in ie9 and disappears

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit-button

my issue is that if I keep the submit button outside the form it works on Chrome, and FireFox, on both desktop and mobile as well as the standard mobile "browser" that comes with cell phones.

But with IE9 nothing happens when I click submit. if I put the submit button inside the form tags it disappears from all browsers. I'm so confused. here is the form code:

```
<form class="mainselection" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="get" name="volunteerlocationlisting">
        <select style="padding: 8px;" onchange="ga('send', 'event', 'volunteerLocator', 'click', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" id="volunteerLocator" name="volunteerLocator">
        <option class=" " value="#" selected="selected">  &nbsp Select your location</option>
      value="http://northwestern.myccsschedule.ca/events/index">White River</option>
        <option name="Windsor-Essex County" value="http://essexcounty.myccsschedule.ca/events/index">Windsor-Essex County</option>
        <option name="Woodstock" value="http://oxfordcounty.myccsschedule.ca/events/index">Woodstock</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" onclick="window.open(volunteerLocator.value,'_self'); _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'VolunteerScheduleLocationDropdown', 'click', VolunteerLocator.options[VolunteerLocator.selectedIndex].getAttribute('name')]);" value="Search" id="daf_srch_btn" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="Submit" />
    </center>
    </form>
```

It's a lot longer than that I simply shortened it because all it is, are a bunch of options, the main part I'd guess for you guys to see would be the input and submit button with the javascript code. I'm also using google analytics to track the page, I haven't had any errors on Chrome or Firefox when checking the console, so I don't know what's wrong.

this is how it is now, and for some reason it disappears within the form tag, the platform this is being built upon is called Leadpages which can be used to publish to various other platforms such as wordpress, facebook, or your own site.

Appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: There's no submit button in the provided snippet.

Comment: it should be `type='submit'` not button. A button element is completely different. when I say button element I mean: `<button></button>`

Comment: whoops that was me messing around, I have `type='submit'`put back in, it still disappears within the form tag, but works outside of it. Now here's the weird thing, I placed two `</form>` tags one before and one after the submit button and it shows up now but still doesn't work in IE9

Comment: When a submit button in a form is clicked, the form is submitted and you'll see the server response. Opening a new window with name `_self` opens the window to the current tab, hence that might be a problem?

Comment: this is the webpage http://cancer.leadpages.co/daffodil-volunteers/ I can't for the life of me figure out the issue. currently i have the extra `</form>` tag so that it shows the submit button

Comment: @Teemu  i tried using _blank but still no luck, just tried to change the `window.open` to `window.location.href=` but I don't think I'm using it right, when I use the = sign it opens a page but as an error